# AFNetworking Block the UI

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to request data from server, in case of bad internet connection, it will take a long time to receive data , so if i don't want to wait and decided to go back, it will not allow me (block the UI), what i should do to be able to go back if i don't want to wait for data to be loaded.

Below is the code which I have used for API call:

```
class func  performHTTPGetOnUrl(url: NSString , withParams dictionary: NSMutableDictionary? , withDelegate delegate:ConnectionManagerDelegate)
{
    print("url is \(url) & params are \(dictionary)")
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: []) //1
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer() //2
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects: "application/json") as Set<NSObject>
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>

    //3

    manager.GET(url as String,
        parameters: dictionary,
        success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

            print("inside connectionManager success")

            delegate.requestSucceededWithJsonResponse(responseObject!)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            print("inside failure block of get ")
            delegate.requestFailedWithError(error!)
    })


}
```

Comment: run it on dispatch_async queue and not on main queue. After completion update the data on main queue.

Comment: This code is already asynchronous. It won't block anything.

Comment: can you provide a simple code on  using dispatch_async queue @ sharad chauhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what could be blocking the UI looking at this code, since those methods (should be) asynchronous already... do you have something that calls this code that blocks until this webservice call is finished? otherwise try wrap the whole thing in a dispatch queue like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
 // do stuff
});
```

your delegate callbacks though should go back onto the main thread in case there are ui updates

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    delegate.requestSucceededWithJsonResponse(responseObject!)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All your **UI updates** must be done in the main thread. You can check if your current flow is on the main thread with this condition and decide to call the `dispatch_get_main_queue` if it's necessary:

```
if NSThread.isMainThread() {
   print("this flow is in the main thread..")
} else {
   print("warning, this is not the main thread..")
   // apply your dispatch_get_main_queue..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add time interval for your request. If the response not get in that time interval then request will get cancelled. Use the below code for add time interval to request.

```
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:30];
```